# Ajax post in wordpress

Tags: jquery, post, wordpress

I am trying to submit a form using post using ajax method in wordpress by following this link.
http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/
I have got stuck at a point a ajax call goes to 
http://www.yourwpdirectory.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 
but it does not return me anything thereby redirecting me to the action call using a browser request.

Can anyone provide me a  simple way in which I can make a ajax post in wordpress.

---

I am updating the plugin code as per the link given above:

```
  <?php


/*
 * Plugin Name: My plugin
 * Description: test plugin
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Interview Coordinator 
 */







add_action("wp_ajax_my_user_vote", "my_user_vote");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_user_vote", "my_must_login");

function my_user_vote() {

   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "my_user_vote_nonce")) {
      exit("No naughty business please");
   }   

   $vote_count = get_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", true);
   $vote_count = ($vote_count == '') ? 0 : $vote_count;
   $new_vote_count = $vote_count + 1;

   $vote = update_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", $new_vote_count);

   if($vote === false) {
      $result['type'] = "error";
      $result['vote_count'] = $vote_count;
   }
   else {
      $result['type'] = "success";
      $result['vote_count'] = $new_vote_count;
   }

   if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
      $result = json_encode($result);
      echo $result;
   }
   else {
      header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
   }

   die();

}

function my_must_login() {
   echo "You must log in to vote";
   die();
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "my_voter_script", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my_plugin/my_voter_script.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my_voter_script' );

}


   $votes = get_post_meta($post->ID, "votes", true);
   $votes = ($votes == "") ? 0 : $votes;
?>
This post has <div id='vote_counter'><?php echo $votes ?></div> votes<br>

<?php
   $nonce = wp_create_nonce("my_user_vote_nonce");

  // $nonce = 123;
    $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_user_vote&post_id='.$post->ID.'&nonce='.$nonce);
//     echo '<a class="user_vote" data-nonce="' . $nonce . '" data-post_id="' . $post->ID . '" href="' . $link . '">vote for this article</a>';

 echo '<a class="user_vote" data-nonce="' . $nonce . '" data-post_id="' . $post->ID . '" href="' . $link . '">vote for this article</a>';


    ?>
```

---

my_voter_script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

   jQuery(".user_vote").click( function() {
      post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-post_id")
      nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce")

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "my_user_vote", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               jQuery("#vote_counter").html(response.vote_count)
            }
            else {
               alert("Your vote could not be added")
            }
         }
      })   

   })

})
```

Comment: Show your code please! We can't help you if we don't know what you're trying

Comment: @ RRikesh: I followed the steps given in the article.

Comment: Then post the actual code you are using here, we’ll have a look. If you want to use Ajax, why not read the official WordPress documentation? http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: @RRikesh: It would be of great help.. If you could provide any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on reference site Are you adding code in your custom plugin ?

I yes, Active this plugin.

And your plugin folder should be "my_plugin".

This script work fine for me.

Comment: I was referring this code to get my code working.. I  just now tried create the plugin as it is. it is giving me an error with wp_create_nonce

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Working Code**

single.php

```
<?php
   $votes = get_post_meta($post->ID, "votes", true);
   $votes = ($votes == "") ? 0 : $votes;
?>
This post has <div id='vote_counter'><?php echo $votes ?></div> votes<br>

<?php
   $nonce = wp_create_nonce("my_user_vote_nonce");
    $link = admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=my_user_vote&post_id='.$post->ID.'&nonce='.$nonce);
    echo '<a class="user_vote" data-nonce="' . $nonce . '" data-post_id="' . $post->ID . '" href="' . $link . '">vote for this article</a>';
?>
```

Create a plugin folder my_plugin
create two files 
 1. plugin.php
 2. my_voter_script.js

plugin.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Ajax test
Plugin URI: 
Description: 
Author: Yatendra
Version: 1.0
*/


add_action("wp_ajax_my_user_vote", "my_user_vote");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_my_user_vote", "my_must_login");

function my_user_vote() {

   if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "my_user_vote_nonce")) {
      exit("No naughty business please");
   }   

   $vote_count = get_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", true);
   $vote_count = ($vote_count == '') ? 0 : $vote_count;
   $new_vote_count = $vote_count + 1;

   $vote = update_post_meta($_REQUEST["post_id"], "votes", $new_vote_count);

   if($vote === false) {
      $result['type'] = "error";
      $result['vote_count'] = $vote_count;
   }
   else {
      $result['type'] = "success";
      $result['vote_count'] = $new_vote_count;
   }

   if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
      $result = json_encode($result);
      echo $result;
   }
   else {
      header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
   }

   die();

}

function my_must_login() {
   echo "You must log in to vote";
   die();
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "my_voter_script", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/my_plugin/my_voter_script.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'my_voter_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my_voter_script' );

}
?>
```

my_voter_script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

   jQuery(".user_vote").click( function() {
      post_id = jQuery(this).attr("data-post_id")
      nonce = jQuery(this).attr("data-nonce")

      jQuery.ajax({
         type : "post",
         dataType : "json",
         url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
         data : {action: "my_user_vote", post_id : post_id, nonce: nonce},
         success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {
               jQuery("#vote_counter").html(response.vote_count)
            }
            else {
               alert("Your vote could not be added")
            }
         }
      })   

   })

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.. But when i go to check the ajax url in the console then an url does not return anything.. and the page gets redirected... How did u fix this issue?